# Why can't I access the instance.__class__ attribute in Python?

Tags: python, class-attribute

I'm new to Python, and I know I must be missing something pretty simple, but why doesn't this very, very simple code work?

```
class myClass:
    pass

testObject = myClass
print testObject.__class__
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: class myClass has no attribute '__class__'
```

Doesn't every object in Python have a `__class__` attribute?

Comment: Error only exists in Python 2.x. In Python 3.1 the `__class__` does not generate an error. And, why are you still using old-style class?

Comment: @KennyTM - this might be dense but... what are old style classes?

Comment: Classes which don't derive from `object`.

Comment: @KennyTM - in Python, are you supposed to explicitly derive all classes from object? (And if so, why?)

Comment: All new-style classes should derive from `object` in the top level. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python for detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I realized my mistake. I thought that the code `testObject = myClass` was creating a new instance/object of the class, but it was actually assigning a reference to the class itself. I changed the code to:

```
class myClass: 
    pass 

testObject = myClass() 
print testObject.__class__
```

and it now works as I was expecting

Answer (score 2):

Most, but not all, objects in Python have a `__class__` attribute. You can usually access it to determine an object's class.

You can get the class of *any* object by calling `type` on it.

```
>>> class myClass:
...     pass
... 
>>> testObject = myClass
>>> type(testObject)
<type 'classobj'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Old-style classes don't have a `__class__` attribute.

```
class myClass(object):
    pass
```